# Line information/number from Textbox in Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight

**Area :**
Textbox in Silverlight

**Question:**
I need to know what "line number" that is currently edited.

**I've tried:**
As a workaround I've tried splitting with textBox.Split("\r") and counting matches on Regex with similar performance. Performance during the first 2000 lines are acceptable but then it gets to slow.

**Why:**
I have a Textbox and a Listbox side-by-side. The item index in the listbox corresponds to line number in the textbox and the content (of the ListboxItem) is a "processed" version of the corresponding line in textbox.

**Alternative:**
A more performance friendly strategy than my hacks.

Comment: Can you show us the regular expression? It is very possible that it needs some optimization.

Comment: Well, I declared it as a member:
private readonly Regex split = new Regex("\r", RegexOptions.Multiline);

Then I use this to get the line count:
this.split.Matches(this.textBoxRawCode.Text).Count

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, you don't really need to use `string.Split` or `Regex`. Just iterate over the string and count `'\r'`s up to the caret position.

```
var s = ...the string...
var r = 0;
var c = ...caret position...

for (var i = 0; i < c; i++)
  if (s[i] == '\r')
    r++;
```

This way, you'll find the line number without creating lots and lots of objects in memory...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution. Feel free to improve the code.

Demo -> http://briggs69.blogspot.com/2011/08/solution-maxlines-property-in.html

Source -> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/XTextBox.aspx